# Hide Add To cart Button in WordPress Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to hide Addtocart button in all pages **when user is not login in the site.**
Also, I used this code for hiding the Price and AddtoCart.

```
if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
    /****** REMOVE THE ADD TO CART BUTTON ****/
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10);

    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10);
   /*********** REMOVE PRICE FROM ALL PLACES *******/
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html', 'theme_remove_prices', 10, 2 );
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'theme_remove_prices', 10, 2 );
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'theme_remove_prices', 10, 2 );
}

function theme_remove_prices( $price, $product ) {
    $price = '';
    return $price;
}
```

**but unfortunately it did not work in all situations**.
**I need to hide AddtoCart in these pages which I showed in the images**.

[image]

**and this one**

[image]

I was wondering If you could help me to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible way is to make the product unpurchasable for not logged in user.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', '__return_false' );
```

Even if you wish you can hide the button through custom CSS.

```
li.product .add_to_cart_button, .single-product form.cart{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your tips. it was helpful. add_filter worked for AddToCard, but for basket button I changed the theme to solve the problem.